# Is there a faster alternative to Array.Exists for huge sorted int arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am having two sorted int Arrays (both one-dimensional, Array1 could have up to several million entries, Array2 will probably be a lot smaller, I am thinking six figures, no duplicates) where I have to perform a matching operation. I am wondering if simply using Array.Exists would be the fastest way to do it or if there is a faster method specifically for finding exact matches of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's sorted, you can use [`Array.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will be O(log n) instead of O(n):

```
int index = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, targetValue);
if (index >= 0)
{
    // Found!
}
```

(`BinarySearch` returns a negative number if the value wasn't found; that's the bitwise complement of the index at which you would insert the value to maintain ordering.)

Alternatively, if your values are distinct, try creating a `HashSet<int>` instead of the array - that will take more memory, but *may* provide an even faster lookup. It's amortized O(1) instead of O(log N), but the constant factor may well make the binary search quicker anyway. You should definitely test this rather than assuming one will be faster than the other.

Note that even for linear searches, if you're looking for an equality match then `Contains` is simpler than `Exists`, as you don't need to provide a delegate (just a value).

Comment: Wanted to suggest the same: Try the hashset: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, you have to write a custom comparer that reflects your predicate.

Comment: @SebastianStehle: You don't have to write a custom comparer. You *can* do, but just `new HashSet<int>()` will work fine.

Comment: @SebastianStehle You have to note your suggestion has already added before you by jon :)

Comment: @Jon: You are right, was too lazy to read, that it is all about int-arrays ;)

Comment: `HashSet` doesn't allow duplicates. Perhaps `Dictionary<int, int>` where value is the nr. of items of the key would be more appropriate depending on the needs.

Comment: @Magnus numbers in the Array will be unique, I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Haris Then `HashSet<int>` would be the correct choice of data-structure.

Comment: @Magnus: I wouldn't like to claim it's definitely the correct choice. I'd want to see data on that first. Don't forget that the algorithmic complexity doesn't say anything about the constant factor. A `HashSet` will take more memory and be more sparsely distributed, which could have an impact on CPU cache usage. (Then again, a binary search will jump about in memory more.) I think it would be better to test both options with the OP's real data than assume either way.

Comment: I'll do that then, implement both and run some Benchmarks with real data. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

If array is sorted you can use [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Create a HashSet for both and use Enumerable.Intersect().

If you don't need the whole thing, still HashSet is superior.
HashSet.Contains is O(1), so if you are looking for n matches you'll have 2n*O(1) instead of n*(O(log p)+O(log q), where p and q are your array lengths.